# Does Stored procedure raise deadlock

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure

```sql
ALTER procedure [dbo].[PRCGetNextValue](
  @sequence_name   varchar(100),
  @pacsid varchar(50),
  @nextsequence bigint output)
as
begin
  update sequences set nextsequenceid = nextsequenceid + 1
                   where pacsid=@pacsid and sequencename=@sequence_name;

  select @nextsequence = nextsequenceid from sequences
                   where pacsid=@pacsid and sequencename=@sequence_name; 
end
```

And I am invoking this SP from C# code and the returned value is used as a primary key for another table.

All this transaction is done in a single `begin / end transaction`.

I tried to invoke the C# method parallel using `Parallel.Invoke();` for around 3000 records and there is no deadlock yet.
Am I doing the analysis in correct way, or does this SP fall in to Deadlock at any time.

Comment: It sounds like you are manually managing Id values / primary keys. If so, that's a bad decision, let SQL server manage Id values for you. The SQL engine will do a better job of it.

Comment: yes we are doing so. we have a situation where we need to merge around 900 DB in to single DB at  later stage. We thought of replication but we have very poor infrastructure at clients place .so we  are trying this approch

Comment: If this is wrapped in a transaction, then you probably don't have a *deadlock* problem.  Instead, you would have a *performance* problem, because you have forced sequential processing for this particular code.

Comment: yes  Performance is an issue.But in this situation performance is having a low priority then the consistency and accuracy of the data

Comment: You only need one statement. `update sequences set @nextsequence = nextsequenceid +=1 where pacsid=@pacsid and sequencename=@sequence_name;`.

Comment: You normally don't get a deadlock from running multiple instances of same code. You normally get a deadlock from running different codes where one code holds resource A and wants resource B and the other code holds resource B and wants resource A. You only have resource A.

Comment: Ok.So you mean the above lines of code does not give us a deadlock situation.

Comment: yes GSerg. I missed that small Logic . Thank you for updating that update statement.

Comment: That particular code should not deadlock with itself, yes. It only wants locks on one table, and that should only result in waiting. Also you might want to look at [CREATE SEQUENCE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).

Comment: yes. But this code will be accessed by around 900 + users concurrently . I that situation . is there any possibility of time out or deadlock

Comment: In principle you cannot get rid of deadlocks completely. You can only reduce the chance they appear and you can handle it gracefully in your application when they do. This code is *very unlikely* to deadlock on itself.

Comment: Ok thank you GSerg

Comment: As of today the Client is using SQL 2008 R2 only